# MySQLがインストールできない

Tags: mysql, macos

環境はmacのyosemiteです。ターミナルはiTermです。

[Mac OS へMySQLをインストールする方法](http://www.yukun.info/blog/2013/03/mac-mysql-install.html)

上記サイトの順序を踏んでインストールしたのですが、

```
mysqladmin -u root password
```

のところで入力すると、

```
-bash: mysqladmin: command not found
```

と表示されます。

というかそもそも同じものをダウンロードしましたが、`mysql-5.6.24-osx10.8-x86_64.pkg` しか入っていませんでした。

正直、調べようにも解説サイトにはいろいろなやりかたがあって、どれを選んでいいのかわからず、もっというと何がわからないのかもわからない状態です。どなたかお助けください。

Comment: iTerm上で「$ mysql -u root」と打っても「command not found」となります。もう何にもできなくてお手上げの状態です。「$」ってつけたほうがいいんですか？　デフォルトの状態が「username-no-macbook-air:~ username$」と表示されているので、追加で打ち込むと「username-no-macbook-air:~ username$ $ mysql -u root」となるので……。どちらが正しいのでしょうか？

Comment: `ls /usr/local/mysql/bin/`
とするとどうなりますか?

Comment: ファイルの一覧のようなものが45個も表示されました。「innochecksum」から始まり「mysql_convert_table_format」などのmysqlと頭についた単語がズラーっと並びました。

Comment: なるほど、では原因はわかったので回答のほうで書きます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問中の参照サイトに `export PATH` で始まる部分がありますが、その手順を実行していないか、または実行した後にターミナルを再起動していないのが原因だと思います。

もしくはログインシェルをbashから変更している可能性もあります。ターミナルで
`echo $SHELL`
と実行してみて、 /bin/bash と出てくればターミナルを再起動するか、もしくは `source ~/.bash_profile` すれば動きます。

UNIXやLinuxでは、コマンドを実行するときにそのコマンドがどこにあるのかを `PATH` という環境変数に設定されている場所から探すのですが、 `mysql`コマンドや`mysqladmin`コマンドが、`/usr/local/mysql/bin`というPATHに入っていない場所にあるため、OSがコマンドを見つけられないのが原因です。
`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin` というのが、既存のPATHに`/usr/local/mysql/bin`を加えるという意味です。`~/.bash_profile`に書くことで、ログインするたびに前述の`export`を実行するので、それ以降OSが勝手に`/usr/local/mysql/bin`の下もコマンドを探してくれるようになります。

Comment: できませんでした。正確にいうと、export PATHから始まる文を打ち込んだのですが何も反応なく、念のため再起動。その後、echo $SHELL と実行し /bin/bash と出たので再起動。source~/.bash_profile も打ちましたが No such file or directory と表示されるだけ。mysqlが動いているか確認のため $ mysql -u root と打ちましたが command not found と表示されます。これ、動いていないってことですよね？

Comment: `mysqladmin -u root password 'パスワード'` を打ち込むと「command not found」と出ます。全く先に進みません。

Comment: `ls /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql` とするとどうなりますか？該当ファイルがあればやはりPATHが通っていないだけです。そもそも ~/.bash_profile がないようなので作ってexport文を書くか、もしくは `~/.bashrc` に書いて `source ~/.bashrc`してください

Comment: とりあえずできました……？　`~/.bash_profile` がなかったので作成し、export文を書いて`mysql -u root`とすると、いつもと違う文章が出てきました。http://joppot.info/2013/12/06/72 ここを参照しました。ただパスワード設定ができません……。`mysqladmin -u root password 'パスワード'`と入れても Warning が出るだけだし、念のため`mysql -u root -p`を入れ、enter password: に入れる（このときなぜか画面にはパスワードが出力されません。*マークすら出ない）と、`ERROR 1045`が出ます。

Comment: -pで画面にパスワードのエコーバックがなにもないのは正常です。1045は単純にアクセス拒否されているのでパスワードが間違っているのではないですか？
mysqladminでパスワードを設定したときのwarningにはなにが出ていたのでしょうか？

パスワードが分からなくなってしまっても、http://liginc.co.jp/web/programming/mysql/87393 こちらの方法でリセットすることは出来るので、試してみてください