# MySQLでパスワードの入力ができない。

Tags: mysql

iterm2 macYOSEMITE使用です

http://qiita.com/sotayamashita/items/b784459356686641dabe
ここを参考に進めていましたが、`mysql.service stop`で止めようとしても`command not found`が返ってきます。

また、ターミナルを立ち上げてすぐの画面で`mysql`と打ち込んでも`command not found`と返されて、MySQLのモードにも入れずの状態です（さっきまでは入れたのですが、モードが解除できなくて一度iTermを落としたらこうなりました）。

かれこれ２０時間くらい色々調べてずっとログインを試みているのですが、いくら試しても全く進展のない状態……。どなたかご教授ください……。

Comment: 原因は http://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/9164/3371 とまったく同じでしょう？

Comment: その質問は解決しましたが、その次のステップとしてこの問題が解決していないのです。

Comment: この問題と前の問題の原因はまったく同じで、ソリューションも同じです。

Answer (score 1):

多分、上手く行ったときって、ターミナル立ち上げて最初にpathを通したんでないですか？
ターミナルを立ち上げ直したら、もう一度pathを通してやらないとダメです。

参考にされたホームページの

```
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
```

って所がそれです。

もし、ターミナルを立ち上げ直す度にpathを通すのがめんどくさかったら、`.bashrc`とかに書いておけば設定の手間がかからなくなりますよ。

Comment: .bashrcがありませんでしたので作成しました。ただそのファイルの編集のやりかたがわからないので探しているところです。

Comment: `export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH`と打ち込むと、直接.bash_profileに書き込まれる、という認識で合っていますよね？　しかし、.bashrcに書き込む場合はどのようにしたら良いのでしょうか……？　ググりまくっていますが全く見つかりません……。

Comment: `mac bashrc`で検索したら見つかりましたよ。
 https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=mac+bashrc

Comment: @akashicrecord 横やりすみません。自分で作って、vimとかで編集できますよ。[macに.bashrcを作成したときのメモ](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/sho-yamasaki/20120505/1336222634)

Comment: `export`についてはこちらをどうぞ。 http://www.ksknet.net/linuxai/expor.html

Comment: ありがとうございます！　どうやらまったく見当違いの検索ワードで探していたみたいです……。これから、教えていただいたところ、しっかり確認させていただきます。

Comment: 私が勘違いしていたところは、.bashecや.bash_profileはMySQL専用のものだと思っていて、それで/use/lodal/mysql/binの直下に作らなければならないものと思っていました。さらに、もともと用意された形式の特別なファイルかと思い、vimなどで作っても良いということがわかっていませんでした。

Comment: いまはdotinstallを見ながら進めているのですが、mysql第三講座にて「mysql -u root」と入力して進められていたのでそのように入力したのですが、「error 1045」と表示されました。しかし、講座とは違うようにただ「mysql」と打ち込んだら「welcome!」と表示されました。プログラミングってコマンドひとつで全く違う結果になったりすると思うので、このように違ったまま進めてよいものか……と不安でしたが、とりあえず進めてみます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: しかし、http://qiita.com/sotayamashita/items/b784459356686641dabe ここで示されているとおりmysqlを止めると「command not found」と表示されてしまいます。また、パスワードはやはり入力できません。

Comment: あーだめだ、結局パスワードの入力ができない……

Comment: `mysql -u root -p`ではいかがですか？

Comment: すると、`Enter password:`と表示されますが、そこで打ち込んでも何も表示されません。また、あらかじめパスワードを設定できていないため、入力するパスワードがありません……。

Comment: `set password for ユーザー名@localhost~password('パスワード');`と打つと「ERROR 1064」となります。どなたかご教授ください……。もう２４時間以上同じところでハマってて進めません……。

Comment: パスワード設定してないのに、パスワードを入力したいんですか？macが無いのでなんなんですが、mysqlをinstallする時にrootのパスワードを変更するか尋ねられませんでしたか？